# Doubts regarding Compiler Construction (Flex/Bison)

Tags: yacc, flex-lexer, compiler-construction

Am trying to construct a simple compiler in my class, its second week and am totally stuck at these points: Am providing my simple.l as (flex and bison files are snipped to save space):

```
..snip..
end     {return(END);}
skip        {return(SKIP);}
in      {return(IN);}
integer {return(INTEGER);}
let     {return(LET);}
..snip..
[ \t\n\r]+
```

and simple.y as :

```
%start program
%token LET IN END 
%token SKIP IF THEN ELSE WHILE DO READ WRITE FI ASSGNOP
%token NUMBER PERIOD COMMA SEMICOLON INTEGER
%token IDENTIFIER EWHILE LT
%left '-' '+'
%left '*' '/'
%right '^'
%%

program : LET declarations IN commands END SEMICOLON
declarations :  
|INTEGER id_seq IDENTIFIER PERIOD
;
id_seq:
|id_seq IDENTIFIER COMMA
;
commands : 
| commands command SEMICOLON
;
command : SKIP
;
exp : NUMBER
| IDENTIFIER
| '('exp')'
;
..snip..
%%
```

My first problem is when I compile and execute this, it properly accepts my input till the end but it does not stop at end; i.e it again comes to start state , isn't it supposed to terminate when it encounters an end :

On the input :

```
let
integer x.
in
skip;
end;
```

here is an output :

```
Starting parse
Entering state 0
Reading a token: let
Next token is token LET ()
Shifting token LET ()
Entering state 1
Reading a token: integer x.
Next token is token INTEGER ()
Shifting token INTEGER ()
Entering state 3
Reducing stack by rule 4 (line 22):
-> $$ = nterm id_seq ()
Stack now 0 1 3
Entering state 6
Reading a token: Next token is token IDENTIFIER ()
Shifting token IDENTIFIER ()
Entering state 8
Reading a token: Next token is token PERIOD ()
Shifting token PERIOD ()
Entering state 10
Reducing stack by rule 3 (line 20):
   $1 = token INTEGER ()
   $2 = nterm id_seq ()
   $3 = token IDENTIFIER ()
   $4 = token PERIOD ()
-> $$ = nterm declarations ()
Stack now 0 1
Entering state 4
Reading a token: in
Next token is token IN ()
Shifting token IN ()
Entering state 7
Reducing stack by rule 6 (line 25):
-> $$ = nterm commands ()
Stack now 0 1 4 7
Entering state 9
Reading a token: skip;
Next token is token SKIP ()
Shifting token SKIP ()
Entering state 13
Reducing stack by rule 8 (line 28):
   $1 = token SKIP ()
-> $$ = nterm command ()
Stack now 0 1 4 7 9
Entering state 19
Reading a token: Next token is token SEMICOLON ()
Shifting token SEMICOLON ()
Entering state 29
Reducing stack by rule 7 (line 26):
   $1 = nterm commands ()
   $2 = nterm command ()
   $3 = token SEMICOLON ()
-> $$ = nterm commands ()
Stack now 0 1 4 7
Entering state 9
Reading a token: end;
Next token is token END ()
Shifting token END ()
Entering state 12
Reading a token: Next token is token SEMICOLON ()
Shifting token SEMICOLON ()
Entering state 20
Reducing stack by rule 1 (line 18):
   $1 = token LET ()
   $2 = nterm declarations ()
   $3 = token IN ()
   $4 = nterm commands ()
   $5 = token END ()
   $6 = token SEMICOLON ()
-> $$ = nterm program ()
Stack now 0
Entering state 2
Reading a token:
```

Why is it ready to read a token again when I have entered end; ?? What am I missing ? Shouldn't it end here ? If I enter anything now it gives me following error :

```
Reading a token: let 
Next token is token LET ()
syntax error, unexpected LET, expecting $end
Error: popping nterm program ()
Stack now 0
Cleanup: discarding lookahead token LET ()
Stack now 0
```

My Second doubt is what should be the next step in implementing this compiler ? I mean what more steps are required between this and code generation part ? How do I implement Symbol table now ? and How do I make this parser accept code from file . Till now am providing input in terminal, what if I want to make this accept code from file like my_program.simple ?
Thank You.

Comment: Its waiting (trying) to read an EOF (end-of-file indication).  Give it an EOF (hit ctrl-D on your terminal) and it should exit cleanly.  Or just redirect from a file, and the file will have an EOF

Comment: Thanks a lot Chris . It cleared by doubt .

Answer (score 1):

```
declarations :  
|INTEGER id_seq IDENTIFIER PERIOD
;
...
```

I think that you're using a wrong syntax: you state that `declarations` (as well as `idseq` and `commands`) could be `epsilon`, i.e. an empty production. That because `|` it's the `alternative` operator. Alternative between an empty body and the actual pattern. Doesn't make sense.

I think could be the cause of your parser looping.

For a symbol table you can use a map (I hope you're generating C++), declared global outside the parser. Then insert symbols when you seen them.

Before to get a compiler, could be useful to have a working *interpreter*, it's easier and clarifies many aspects that will be reused building the compiler.

Comment: It's redundant. If it was wrong, that is to say ambiguous, yacc would have said so. It won't be the cause of the parser looping.